# Passing Alternate Credential to ADSI Commands in Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, adsi

I'm trying to assign permissions to AD OU's using powershell script that is supposed to create a new object of type `System.Security.Principal.NTAccount` and `System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule`, The code I have right now is working without alternate credentials but now I need to use the same code with alternate credentials.

**Working Code without Alternate Credentials:**

```
$ADSI = [ADSI]"LDAP://$OUPath"

$NTAccount = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($ClientGroupED)

$IdentityReference = $NTAccount.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])

$ActiveDirectoryRights = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryRights] "GenericAll"

$AccessControlType = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType] "Deny"

$Inherit = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurityInheritance] "All"  #All, Children, Descendents, None, SelfAndChildren

$ACE = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule($IdentityReference,$ActiveDirectoryRights,$AccessControlType,$Inherit)

$ADSI.psbase.ObjectSecurity.SetAccessRule($ACE)

$ADSI.psbase.commitchanges()
```

I tried passing the alternate credentials using `-Credential $Cred` and also passed the `-ArgumentList $Cred` while calling New-Object neither works. Need some help in this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only place where you're actually talking to AD is at `$ADSI.psbase.commitchanges()`. So the only place you need to set credentials is when you create `$ADSI`.

The `[ADSI]` type accelerator is just a shortcut to creating a [`DirectoryEntry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry) object. `DirectoryEntry` does have a [constructor that accepts credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.-ctor#System_DirectoryServices_DirectoryEntry__ctor_System_String_System_String_System_String_), but to use it, you can't use the type accelerator anymore. You'll need to use `New-Object`, like this:

```
$ADSI = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://$OUPath", "username", "password")
```

Just replace `username` and `password` with credentials that have permission to do what you're doing.

If you want the script to call `Get-Credential` and use whatever credentials the user enters, then you can use the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20423941/1202807).

A side note: you don't need to use `psbase` in the last two lines. You can if you want, but it makes no functional difference. You can do without:

```
$ADSI.ObjectSecurity.SetAccessRule($ACE)

$ADSI.CommitChanges()
```

Comment: This worked for me, completed my task.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Gabriel Luci ----- Any idea how to pass  -credential $Cred to "New-GPLink" command ??
------
New-GPLink -Name "Security_Policy" -Target "OUPath"

Comment: That's just a normal PowerShell cmdlet, so if it doesn't have a `-Credential` parameter, then you can't. But the comment in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61682263/1202807) has some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the credentials directly on the `ADSI` object. I have tested this to set the terminal services properties for a user.

```
$ADSI = [ADSI]("LDAP://" + $userdn)
$ADSI.psbase.Username = $credential.username
$ADSI.psbase.Password = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password 

//get the value of a property
$output["property"] = $ADSI.psbase.InvokeGet("Property")

//set the value of a property
$ADSI.psbase.InvokeSet("Property", "your value")
$ADSI.CommitChanges()
```